# Convert 24 hour format hours into 12 hour format time in php

Tags: php, datetime

How can I convert 24 hour format hours into 12 hour format time in php like 1630 should be 4:30 PM.

there are articles to convert 24 hour format time into 12 hour format time like 16:30 into 04:30 PM but I need to convert hours into time.

I am doing it by dividing it by 1200 and get remainder as minute but I hope there is another way to do it using date or time functions.

Comment: Check my ans for `0900, 0800` as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will work for you.

```
date("h:i a",strtotime("1630"));
```

Comment: yes it worked but not for 0900, 0800  it always shows 1:00 am

Comment: Now it will for 0900, 0800 as well. Actually 0900 was automatically converted into 900 but now as a string it will not.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this

```
<?php
 $date  =  date("Y-m-d 16:30:00");
 echo date("h:i a",strtotime($date));
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/858486

Or if your time is `1630`

```
$time = 1630;
$time = (int)(1630/100).":".(1630%100);
$date  =  date("Y-m-d $time:00");
echo date("h:i a",strtotime($date));
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/858559

Update for 3 digits number like `920` or `815`

```
$time = "0920"; // here $time should be string `0` is for other base of number
$last2 = substr($time, -2);
$time = str_replace($last2,":".$last2,$time);
$date  =  date("Y-m-d $time");
echo date("h:i a",strtotime($date));
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/858555